# image array in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios

i am new to iphone programming, i want to put multiple images for slideview..and for that i want to declare it by array and use it  in same viewcontroller class..so anybody can tell me how to declare the array of images in a class and display

Answer (score 2):

BoYo's solution is fine if you have just a few images, but more than a few images will require a more sophisticated solution, particularly if the images are at higher resolution (as you'll need if you want to be able to zoom in). Images can consume a lot of memory, so you'll want a strategy for loading only the images you need at any given moment and unloading them as you no longer need them. UIScrollView provides for tiling the content, so you can provide the scrolling content just a little at a time. That lets you keep only what you need in memory while still giving decent scrolling performance.

Take a look at the [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080) sample code to see how this can be done well.

Comment: Also, take a look at the WWDC 2010 Scroll View talk, which discusses code very similar to this sample code: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Answer (score 1):

One solution for the scrollview is to create an `UIImageView` for every picture you want to add to your scrollview and then add them as subviews to your scrollview.
As far as for the tap part - you can create your own `GestureRecognizer` for the tap action and set anything you want to do with the selected image. Also try to change `minzoom` and `maxzoom` of the scrollview's contentview and zoom action will be added automatically for you.

Comment: This won't be a good solution for more than a few images. Doing it "right" is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                   nil];
```

Comment: hay thank for the help...i tried this code but it couldn't work...actually i want 5 images view in scrollview with zooming and tapping so can u help me on that? i ll b thankful to you for this help

Comment: can anybody explain how can i zoom images by tapping when that images are stored in a array..i have searched that if there are more images for zoom and tapping then it requires multiple subviews so it would be appreciated if anybody can give suggetion